# Use row values to filter another dataframe with similar column names as input for mutate()

Tags: r, dplyr

Assuming a dataframe as following:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(value=c(1,2,3,4),
             group=as.factor(c("patient", "patient", "control", "control")),
             mode1=as.factor(c("a", "b", "a", "b")),
             mode2=as.factor(c("c", "c", "d", "d")))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
value group   mode1 mode2
    1 patient a     c
    2 patient b     c
    3 control a     d
    4 control b     d
```

I want to run `wilcox.test(df$value ~ df$group, data)` for each possible subset of `df`, when filtering `df` for each combination of `mode1` and `mode2`, and store the result in a different dataframe.

What I would like to get is a dataframe like this:

```
mode1  mode2  val
    a      c  wilcox.result(value~group, filter(df, mode1=="a", mode2=="c"))
    a      d  wilcox.result(value~group, filter(df, mode1=="a", mode2=="d"))
    b      c  wilcox.result(value~group, filter(df, mode1=="b", mode2=="c"))
    b      d  wilcox.result(value~group, filter(df, mode1=="b", mode2=="d"))
```

with `val` being the result of the respective function call.

This is what I got so far:

```
vals <- tidyr::expand(df, mode1, mode2)
vals <- mutate(val = somefun(value~group,
                                 data=filter(df,
                                             mode1==mode1,
                                             mode2==mode2))$p.value)
```

but all `p.value`s are the same, indicating some problem along the way. Assuming I expressed my problem in a comprehensible way, how can I achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Could you be a bit more explicit. Which is `somefun`, or at least, an example for it. Which is the output do you expect?

Comment: Edited as requested. Thanks for helping! English isn't my first language, please let me know if things still aren't clear.

Comment: The example is not yet reproducible (`wilcox.test` on 1 line of data produces an error), but something like `df %>% nest_by(mode1,mode2) %>% mutate(model = list(wilcox.test(value ~ group, data = data)))` is what you want

Comment: Also, this could help you, as @Limey answer: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

Comment: Thank you so much, that's precisely what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Without an MWE (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more information), it's difficult to give you a perfect answer to your question, but here's an example which demonstrates a technique that I *think* will give you what you want to do.  It uses the commonly used `mtcars` data frame as input data and uses `gear` and `carb` in place of your `mode1` and `mode2`.  It fits a regression of `mpg` on `wt` rather than conducting a rank sum test.

```
d <- mtcars %>% group_split(Group=as.factor(interaction(gear, carb)))
bind_rows(lapply(d, function(x) broom::tidy(lm(mpg ~ wt, data=x)) %>%
  add_column(Group=unique(x$Group))))

# A tibble: 19 x 6
   term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value Group
   <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <fct>
 1 (Intercept)   28.4        8.10    3.51     0.177  3.1  
 2 wt            -2.65       2.63   -1.01     0.498  3.1  
 3 (Intercept)   56.6       26.6     2.13     0.167  4.1  
 4 wt           -13.3       12.8    -1.04     0.407  4.1  
 5 (Intercept)   -5.18      22.1    -0.234    0.836  3.2  
 6 wt             6.27       6.20    1.01     0.418  3.2  
 7 (Intercept)   37.0        5.50    6.73     0.0214 4.2  
 8 wt            -4.58       2.00   -2.30     0.149  4.2  
 9 (Intercept)   41.0      NaN     NaN      NaN      5.2  
10 wt            -7.02     NaN     NaN      NaN      5.2  
11 (Intercept)   17.5       22.1     0.791    0.574  3.3  
12 wt            -0.312      5.73   -0.0544   0.965  3.3  
13 (Intercept)   18.3        5.41    3.39     0.0427 3.4  
14 wt            -1.22       1.14   -1.07     0.362  3.4  
15 (Intercept)   30.2        3.61    8.37     0.0140 4.4  
16 wt            -3.38       1.16   -2.92     0.100  4.4  
17 (Intercept)   15.8      NaN     NaN      NaN      5.4  
18 (Intercept)   19.7      NaN     NaN      NaN      5.6  
19 (Intercept)   15        NaN     NaN      NaN      5.8
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question correctly, I suggest using the function `do` form dplyr on groups of your data. Therefore, group the data frame (by `mode1`, `mode2`) and apply on each group (sub set of the data frame) you defined function. For example:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(mode1, mode2) %>% 
  do(
    # your function
    data.frame(wilcox.p_value=wilcox.test(.$value)$p.value)
  )
```